# Adding float values in c

Tags: c, floating-point

Why does f is 0.0 even after adding 0.1?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
  {
    float f=0.0f;
    f = f + 0.1f;
    printf("f %f \n",&f);
    return 0;
  }
```

Sorry for that I messed up with original question

Why these two values are not ? Is this because of precision.
Sorry I have to ask this question here because I'm blocked I can't ask more questions

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float f=0.0f;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
          {f = f + 0.1f; }

    if(f == 1.0f)
            printf("f is 1.0 \n");
    else
            printf("f %f is NOT 1.0\n",f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because you shouldn't pass an **address** to `printf("%f…`. Instead `printf("%f", f)` would be correct.

Comment: …and making your questions confusing by asking a second question at the bottom of the first question is **not** the way to regain the right to ask questions.

Comment: Sorry, I was left with no other option I want answer but I can't ask new question as I'm blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 printf("f %f \n",f);
```

Gives correct output. See here-https://ideone.com/158Zbv

To print address  `printf(" %p \n",&f);` will do it .

Where as your `printf` statement will give undefined behaviour.

About your second code - 
You can re-write your `if` condition like this -

```
if(f>0.99f && f<1.01f)
```

So that it gives you correct output- https://ideone.com/kARx3A

### EDIT

While adding in your program value of `f` is not exactly `1.0f`  but it may have some different value ,when we see its value with more decimal places it is bit different than `1.0f` that's why your code always go to else part .

See here what value `f` has with every iteration-https://ideone.com/wJ7u1R

Comment: no, it won't "print address of `f``", it will merely invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: `printf("f %f \n",&f)` actually gives undefined behaviour, due to mismatch of types.

Comment: It will not print the address of f. It will take the 4 bytes with the adderss of f, and will interpret that as a float, consisting of exponent and mantissa, and will print that as a float.

Comment: Yes , made a mistake .Corrected it .

Comment: @ameyCU can you tell me the reason Why I can't check equality for f and 1.0

Comment: @admin Please see the edit .

Answer (score 0):

you are printing address of variable f by using & operator, remove this & operator.